# A word or short phrase for "Reported not having"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions

In a report, I have a set of experiences a person has reported experiencing, and a set of experiences a person has reported not experiencing.

I want to give these a pithy descriptor since I've got a lot of these people.

"Reported:" is easy, but I can't find a good opposite of it (can't use unreported, since they have reported something).

Candidates so far are: Contra-reported, Reported-not, Not experienced

I prefer Contra-reported but it isn't a used phrase if google is to be believed.

Example:

> Reported: Too much energy, Waking up early
>
> [Word]:  Obsession with costumes

Comment: It’s still *reported*, but in the negative: reported *no obsession* ....

Comment: Your example sentence using *reported* makes no sense whatsoever. Reporting something has *nothing* to do with having too much energy or waking up early. Unless that's the *content* of the report. But that doesn't help explain what *reported* (or its opposite) means.

Comment: In this case, the person may have reported having too much energy and waking up early. Hard to say if they did actually have too much energy

Comment: @JasonBassford   I think you did not understand the use-case of gbartonowen's example. He will use *reported* when an interviewee (obviously a person participating in some psychologocial or medical testing) positively reported having some feeling (or sensation or whatever). He needs a word for "reported that he has not had this feeling" or "reported the non-experiencing of that feeling" or "reported positively that this feeling did not occur". He cannot use "did not report xyz" because this means something different, namely "feeling may have been there, but he did not report it".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann You're correct, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann What you describe is what I described—although you concluded something different. If you *report* something, you *relay*, *tell*, or *describe* something. In other words, the opposite of *report* (which has been focused on) would be something like *lie*, *deceive*, *keep quiet about*, *obscure*, or *recant*. But the way in which the question is phrased conveys almost nothing about what particular sense is required because it's caught up in odd verbiage and presentation. Alternative grammatical negations are *did not report* or *reported the lack of*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Any suggested edits of the question? I hoped it was rather clear. "Did not report" is exactly what I can't use because it has incorrect meaning.

Comment: So, is *reported the lack of* your intended meaning? If so, I would change the focus of your question away from "the opposite of reported" to something like "How to report the absence of something." (Both in the summary and detail.) And, to be clear, do you want a single word that means *reported the lack of*?

Comment: You're correct, I will change the title. I don't think the detail has this lack of clarity

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems the task is to find very brief expressions because you have to use this repeatedly in a research paper or so. So, brevity prevents you to use complicated expressions such as "Reported to not have been experienced".

Under this presumption an obvious thing to do would be:

> Reported: too much energy; waking up early.
>
> Denied: obsession with costumes

If you want more similarity of your terms and if in what you are doing you have the liberty to create terms, you could use

> Reported: too much energy; waking up early.
>
> Disreported: obsession with costumes

I initially thought that *de-reported* would be better because less flashy, but then, *de-reported* could rather mean "first reported, then de-reported" which is not what you want to express (like in *briefing* vs *de-briefing*).

Additional thoughts:

Actually, if you go after the roots of the word in Latin where *reportare* is "bring back" from *re* (back) and *portare* (to bring), it would be a logical thing to work with the prefix:

> Reported: too much energy; waking up early
>
> Disported: obsession with costumes

(Again *deported* would be closer to my mind, but then you run into conflicts with the ordinary meaning of *deported*. You could, of course, spell it *de-ported*, or simply explain your choice of words in the introduction to your study.)

Comment: I would appreciate downvoters to leave a comment why they think this answer is not useful. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't down-vote. I'd be inclined to up-vote if you drop "disreported" and explain why "denied" is a good choice (e.g. because a denial implies the reporting of said denial).